# I have 2 big components/ screens and after a link press on the element I want the whole screen to load the new components without reloading

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 screens named signIn and Signup with their codes below:

signin

```
const SignIn = () => (
<div style={{display:'flex'}}>
  <div style={{flex:2}}>
    <ImageDiv bg={signin} src = {signin} alt="logo">
      <LogoDiv src={logo} alt="logo" />
    </ImageDiv>
  </div>
  <FormDiv>
    <Input style={{marginTop: `${44  }px`}} placeholder="Username" />
    <Input style={{marginTop: `${44  }px`}} placeholder="Password" />
    <Button style={{marginTop: `${45  }px`}}>Sign in</Button>
    <ForgotPassword>Forgot username or password</ForgotPassword>
    <SignUpParagraph>Don’t have an account? Sign up</SignUpParagraph>
  </FormDiv> 
</div>
)

export default SignIn;
```

If I press  I want signup to show without the traditional loading or even using react router i out of the question. the code for the signup is below

signup

```
const SignUpOptions = () => (
    <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
      <SelectOptionDiv>
        <SelectAccountParagraph>Select account type</SelectAccountParagraph>
        <SelectAccountButton>Business</SelectAccountButton>
        <SelectAccountButton style={{marginTop: `${2.1  }%`}}>Freelancer</SelectAccountButton>
        <ExistingAccountParagraph style={{marginBottom: `${20.9  }%`}}>Join an already existing business account</ExistingAccountParagraph>
      </SelectOptionDiv>
      <div style={{flex:2}}>
    <ImageDiv bg={signup} src = {signup} alt="logo" />
  </div>
    </div>

)

export default SignUpOptions;
```

I hope someone can totally guide me at the way to go

Comment: Have a state property like "showSignup": boolean, then have a conditional rendering in your parent component. if(showSignup) render signup; else render whatever else. I'd just use react router with the Link component if it were me though.

Comment: Can you explain to me a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can use component state to decide what to render, this would work without using react router. I'll make a simplified example, but basically you need a wrapper component which decides which component to show.

```
const Wrapper = () => {
    const [showSignUp, toggleShowSignUp] = useState(false);

    if(showSignUp) 
        return <SignUpOptions 
                toggleShowSignUp={() => toggleShowSignup(!showSignUp)} 
               />; 

    return <SignIn toggleShowSignUp={() => toggleShowSignup(!showSignUp)} />;
}
```

Does that answer your question sufficiently? It would work without a page reload or react router.